# Can I put a map in my http api for extensibility?

Tags: json, http

My http api uses JSON to pass parameters, it looks like:

```
{
  param1: xxx
  param2: xxx
  param3: xxx
}
```

However, my system is a plugin system that each plugin needs to have its own parameters in the JSON body and all plugins will cooperate with each other to produce final result.

for example, let's say the api is

```
CreateACar {
   name: xxx
   description: xxx
   model: xxxx
}
```

the base api has three fields for basic meta data. And the system has plugins like:

```
CarColorPlugin: needs parameters as
{
   doorColor: xxx
   roofColor: xxx
   decoratorColor: xxx
}

TirePlugin: needs parameters as
{
   tireSize: xxx
   tireBrand: xxx
}

WindShieldPlugin: needs parameters as
{
   brand: xxx
   needRearWindShield: true or false
}
```

you can imagine this kind of plugins as many as possible. Now the problem is all plugins need api CreateACar to carry their information and sometimes later a new plugin may join the system so CreateACar must be extensible for future needs.

Now I am considering to put a map in JSON body and passing api CreateACar to all plugins so they can fetch parameters by themselves.

However, this design looks a little ugly to me. I have been researching for a while, the projects having beautiful api usually have limited business domain. For projects having broad unanticipated business domain usually use extensible data structure like XML in API body, however, all these API I have seen so far are mess, especially these without good documentation.

Comment: Why not just make `CreateACar` abstract and let the subclasses add whatever fields they need?

Comment: @chrylis that doesn't work, because all plugins need to cooperate to produce the result which means the api must have all information. Subclass for each plugin only gets their own parameters but not all

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, each plugin should have its own JSON object in a field, so you'll need something like a `Map<String,Plugin>`, and possibly custom deserialization logic to dispatch the JSON object to a factory on the appropriate plugin class.

Comment: @chrylis. Yes exactly. Each plugin must register themselves with some parameter identity. Then orchestration code could dispatch workflow and parameters to that plugin when corresponding parameter identity presents in that map.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - presumably many of your requests will ask for *one* car, not *all* of them, though.

Comment: what's problem to ask all of them?

Comment: You don't want all of them. Loading time; could be a huge list. Security - maybe you're not allowed all of them. Etc.

Comment: @zx_wing when you visit a friend's FB profile do you think every single profile in all of FB is sent to your browser? Or even all of your friends'? When you download an email are all the billions of emails in the world loaded, or even all of your own? etc.

Comment: yes the api will only go through plugins needed. I just want to make sure this design of putting a map in api is not any antipattern. I also wonder how successful project handles similar problem? Though I didn't find an example.

Comment: @zx_wing what do you think viewing your inbox is? or your FB news feed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my overall design suggestion:

- Use the Java SPI system to handle your plugins. Define a plugin interface that includes a method to identify the plugin's key (`"color"`, `"wipers"`, and so on) and one that takes a `Map` and returns a plugin data object. Collect all of the implementations in a `Map<String,Plugin>`.
- Write a `getPlugins()`  method on your `Car` class that does not have a backing field but instead collates the information from all of the plugins applied to the `Car` in a nested `Map`.
- Write a `setPlugins()` method that takes the nested map, iterates over the keys, looks up the appropriate factory plugin by name, and rehydrates the plugin data object from the JSON object data.

Comment: actually I know how to do it in java part. The problem here is my api is http based, I am not sure putting a map in the post body is good practice or antipattern